# Ajax with Express and jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express

I have a browse page in my app where people can add an item either as owned or wanted. Right now it's redirecting back to the general /browse page, but I'd like for the page to not be refreshed at all. I'm trying to do this via ajax, but am super new at this and haven't been able to get it working. Here is my code, I really appreciate the assistance:

```
//HTML file
<div>
    <center><div class="hover">+</div>
    <div class="hovermenu"><a class="addown" pid="<%= p[i].id %>" href="#">&#10004;</a></a></div></center>
</div>


$(".addown").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/addown/' + $(this).('pid'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().replaceWith('<center><span>&#10004;</span></center>')
        }
    })
    e.preventDefault();
});




//Server side
app.post('/addown/:id', function(req, res) {
    req.user.owned.addToSet(req.params.id);
    req.user.save();
    res.end();
});
```

Any assistance is really appreciated!

Comment: I don't think "this" is what you expect it to be after the ajax call.

Comment: So I would want to say $(.addown), but how do I specify that I want the one that was originally clicked?

Comment: Save it, add `var ref = this;` above the ajax call and then `$(ref).parent...`

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
url: '/addown/' + $(this).('pid'),
```

has a syntax error, ibelieve you want to get the pid attribute

```
url: '/addown/' + $(this).attr('pid')
```

In you success callback this is not the div, to set the context of the callback to the div use `context` in your ajax params

```
url: '/addown/' + $(this).attr('pid'),
context: this,
```

Comment: You are correct! I fixed that, so now the console is actually showing the click as doing something. However, the div is not replacing with the checkmark correctly. Any ideas?